# Variable scoping in Google Calendar API call with Node and Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, express, google-calendar-api

I'm currently writing an app using Angular/Node/Express that will pull data from my Google Calendar, using an API Get call. First I'm focusing on getting the back-end setup. I've been following some tutorials and got my server.js file set up accordingly:

```
// Get dependencies
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Get our API routes
const api = require('./server/routes/api');

const app = express();

// Parsers for POST data
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// Point static path to dist
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

// Set our api routes
app.use('/api', api);

// Catch all other routes and return the index file
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/newcal-angular/index.html'));
});

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */
const port = process.env.PORT || '3000';
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */
const server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */
server.listen(port, () => console.log(`API running on localhost:${port}`));
```

I've followed [Google's Node.js Quickstart page](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/nodejs) and have their boilerplate block of code inside my "server/routes/api.js" file:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

let events;

/* GET api listing. */
router.get('/', (req, res, Data) => {

  res.send("gonna start sending things");

  const fs = require('fs');
  const readline = require('readline');
  const { google } = require('googleapis');

  // If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
  const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'];
  const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';

  // Load client secrets from a local file.
  fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
    if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
    // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Calendar API.
    authorize(JSON.parse(content), listEvents);
  });

  /**
  * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
  * given callback function.
  * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
  * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
  */
  function authorize(credentials, callback) {
    const { client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris } = credentials.installed;
    const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

    // Check if we have previously stored a token.
    fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
  }

  /**
  * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
  * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
  * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
  * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback for the authorized client.
  */
  function getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
    const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
      access_type: 'offline',
      scope: SCOPES,
    });
    console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
      input: process.stdin,
      output: process.stdout,
    });
    rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
      rl.close();
      oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
        if (err) return console.error('Error retrieving access token', err);
        oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
        // Store the token to disk for later program executions
        fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
          if (err) console.error(err);
          console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
        });
        callback(oAuth2Client);
      });
    });
  }

  /**
  * Lists the next 10 events on the user's primary calendar.
  * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
  */
  function listEvents(auth) {

    const calendar = google.calendar({ version: 'v3', auth });
    calendar.events.list({
      calendarId: 'primary',
      timeMin: (new Date()).toISOString(),
      maxResults: 10,
      singleEvents: true,
      orderBy: 'startTime',
    }, (err, res) => {
      if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      this.events = res.data.items;
      if (this.events.length) {
        console.log('Upcoming 10 events:');
        this.events.map((event, i) => {
          const start = event.start.dateTime || event.start.date;
          console.log(`${start} - ${event.summary}`);
        });
      } else {
        console.log('No upcoming events found.');
      }
    });
  }
})

module.exports = router;
```

It looks like all the real magic is happening inside of the "listEvents(auth)" function, and the variable I would like to return back to my Angular function after a Get call is what's contained in the "this.events" variable.

**Question**: How do I do that? As far as I can tell, all of my code is executing correctly: When I run "node server.js" I see all the correct data show up in my console, and when I navigate to localhost:3000 I see "gonna start sending things". I'm just not sure how to scope the "this.events" variable outside of its function and send it back.

Thank you for all of your help! I've searched Google's API documentation for days and it's unfortunately lacking in the Node language, and I'm still new to implementing asyncs/awaits/promises/etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just take a look on a package called [node-google-calendar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-google-calendar). I also have a project that send, retrieve, update, delete data from Google Calendar using node-google-calendar package, express and node. Here's my repository: https://github.com/hfbchri/manajemen_event

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's a simple solution: I didn't realize res.send couldn't be called multiple times. I deleted it from under `router.get` and instead only inserted `res.send(this.events)`under `this.events = response.data.items`. It's returning my data properly now. Still getting a better grasp on async functions but this at least got my code working.